# How to handle java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character for all the special charcters

Tags: java, regex, replaceall, patternsyntaxexception

I want to handle  java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character
caused by any special character.
For example Assume the following string

```
String var = "Hi * How / are \\ you + ";
String replacement = var.replaceAll(var,"Replaced");
```

I want to handle above code as such I need not add `\\` for each replacing each special characters.

PS: There can be many more special characters other than the one mentioned. I want to create a condition to handle all the characters which would return this exception.

PPS: I have to use `replaceAll`. I cannot use `replace` as I'm working in java version 1.4. Also cannot upgrade java version.

I am stuck with version 1.4. And `Pattern.quote` will work on java 1.5 onwards.

Comment: Are you always replacing the entire `var` string?  Is there any reason why you can't just say `String replacement = "Replaced";`?

Comment: @rgettman This is just an example to show what I want.  I will be replacing multiple lines of a text file. In those lines, these special characters can be there. The original string will be the text file content from which I have to remove few lines.